# Authorization Code Grant error: invalid authentication request

Tags: docusignapi

Our attempts at authentication have thus far returned only errors as we try to follow the directions detailed here: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant

When we send this response:

`https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=3f67330c-2cbf-43f6-9ea5-e295cd646840&redirect_uri=http://138.68.27.51:8080/signCallback#/username`

we get an error: "Invalid authentication request: The response type is not supported."

The type is **code** as described in the **Authorization Code Grant** document.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If 'code' grant type is returning the 'not supported' error, it's most likely because you've checked the 'This is a mobile app' checkbox for the integrator key. To resolve, log in to DocuSign > Go to Admin > API & Keys > Edit the ikey > Uncheck the mobile app checkbox.

Checking that box disables Code Grant and enables the Implicit Grant workflow (documented here: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-implicit)

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to respond!