# Confused about the Authorization Code Grant

Tags: docusignapi

I am attempting to do implement an authorization code grant I start by calling (from the browser):

https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=1ee7dba4-ca87-4451-8b82-a5df0d95fa41&state=a39fh23hnf23&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4000/docusign/authGrantReturn/

Sometimes I am asked for login/password, which always tells me that the response type is not supported or that the user/pass are not valid. I found this previous answer ([Authorization Code Grant error: invalid authentication request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869092/authorization-code-grant-error-invalid-authentication-request)) but did not find the checkbox discussed.

Otherwise, it calls back my rediect url (*handled in node*), and provides me with a 'code' and returns the 'state' I previously sent, and here begins my confusion:

I make an http request using the fetch library like so:

```
let combination = `${integrationKey}:${secretKey}`;
let b64Combination = Buffer.from(combination).toString('base64');

fetch('https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token?grant_type:authorization_code&code='+b64Combination,{
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ${b64Combination}', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',  'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'}
})
.then...
```

But this returns html content in the body.

1. Does that mean I should make the call to https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token from the browser rather than node?
2. When it asks me to log in, am I to use my sand-box account credentials? or the credentials of a regular docusign user?

Sorry for the confused question...

Best regards,
Adrian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use the DocuSign nodeJS SDK and code example.

https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-node-auth-code-grant

Follow the instructions here, this code makes it very simple and if you update all your info - it just works. 
Then, you can see how to modify it to your needs.
(for your second question, yes, for now you use your sandbox creds when you build/test your app)